# How to change color of specific word(s) from input box vba powerpoint vba beginner

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am very new to vba (only started just yesterday) but would like to use code to save some time with filling forms in powerpoint. I have thus far figured out how to generate an input box with resulting textbox and change font color if only a single word is entered and is a match. This, however, doesn't completely fit my needs.

For my purposes, the user input convention would be "Word1-Word2-Word3-Word4-Word5". For instance, "Red-Yellow-Orange-Green-Blue". I would like for Red to turn red, yellow to turn yellow, orange to turn orange, and so forth. Dashes would remain black. The input could be in any order and not all parts may be present (ie. "Yellow-Red-Green-Blue-Orange" or "Red-Blue-Green" could happen) but color coding needs to be preserved.

```
<here is where I should put my current code that doesn't exactly fit my needs>
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you'll take the user-supplied text string and add it to a text box on a slide.  The following example assumes that the text box is selected; your code will need to  insert a new text box and get a reference to it in a variable (oSh in this case).

```
Sub Example()
' This looks for the word "red" in the currently selected
' shape's text and if found, turns it red.

    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oRng As TextRange
    
    ' Get a reference to the currently selected shape
    ' For what you're doing, you'd need slightly different code
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    ' Get a reference to the text range that contains the word "red"
    Set oRng = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Find("red")

    ' Change the color of the text range containing the word "red"
    ' RealWorld Notes:
    ' Test to see if oRng Is Nothing ... which it'll be if there's 
    ' no word "red" in the string
    ' You'll need to deal with capitalization: "red" vs "Red" etc.        
    oRng.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     
End Sub
```